# The Football Murder Mystery

Tags: cipher, mystery, alphametic

> "THE COACH IS DEAD". 
>   That's the news buzzing around the country.
>   There always was a sort of hatred towards the coach after he failed to guide the Team into the Olympics in football even after they were one of the stronger teams. Yet, this was unprecedented. The Circumstances of his death clearly show murder. He was stabbed in the back with a knife in the dressing room of the stadium. The knife was nowhere to be found. He had been murdered between 1600-1700 hours in the previous day. Only the players were present in that time near the dressing room. Thus, suspicions landed on them and it was determined that it had to be one of the 11 players of the team that had murdered him. Further investigations show that the coach knew that his life was in danger. A diary was found on his table.
>
> It read: FbyirgurPelcgnevguz
>
> He was a fan of ciphers. This was a good way not to arouse any suspicions in the mind of the murderer.
>
> Further on the next page it read:
>
> $$ SEND+MORE=MONEY $$
>
> Now this confused everyone. No one could make head or tail of it.
>
> Lastly, here's is the information about the Players..
>
> REED-     GOALKEEPER-            JERSEY NO.1
>
> ED-       DEFENDER-              JERSEY NO.2
>
> SEN-      DEFENDER-              JERSEY NO.20
>
> RON-      DEFENDER-              JERSEY NO.15
>
> MOOSE-    DEFENDER-              JERSEY NO.4
>
> ENDO-     MIDFIELDER-            JERSEY NO.18
>
> SOMERY-   MIDFIELDER-            JERSEY NO.8
>
> DORES-    MIDFIELDER-            JERSEY NO.25
>
> DORM-     MIDFIELDER-            JERSEY NO.17
>
> ROY-      STRIKER-               JERSEY NO.9
>
> ORMEND-   STRIKER-               JERSEY NO.16
>
> Can you find out who murdered the Coach?

P.S. I know this is easy. I actually lost my original puzzle and now made do with a hastily made one. I don't have much time next week. Hence, thought would post a puzzle on a Sunday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was

> Endo, jersey number 18

since he was

> the only one whose name's corresponding digits in the SEND+MORE=MONEY alphametic summed to his jersey number.

The solution to the alphametic is

> O: 0
> M: 1
> Y: 2
> E: 5
> N: 6
> D: 7
> R: 8
> S: 9

with final equation

> 9567 + 1085 = 10652.

Comment: While the answer is correct, I would ask you to Solve the alphametics and show which letter corresponds to which digits.(With explanations)

Comment: I wanted the logic to the alphametic. I know wikipedia directly gives the answer. But, I wanted to know the thought process of someone who solved it..

Comment: @Sid http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/51/

Comment: Well, Detective Columbo, that will never hold up in a court of law.  So, are you saying that the first diary entry has ***nothing*** to do with it?

Comment: @PeregrineRook Solve it. You will see why Deusovi didn't mention it..